# Test if Generic Method can be invoked on Parameters list

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, system.reflection

Let's say I have a generic method (retrieved from parent type with reflection):

```
void MyType::MyMethod<T>(T[], int, int)
```

I want to know if I can invoke that method on some type list:

```
byte[], int32, int32
```

Obviously the answer is yes.

However I'd like to find a generic way to **find the best overload** (among several generics) **matching a parameter list**.

I can easily get all methods:

```
MyType.GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "MyMethod")
```

then filter to match parameter count:

```
.Where(m => m.GetParameters().Count() == 3)
```

but then I'm blocked.

[EDIT AS REQUESTED IN COMMENTS]

```
var methods = typeof(Array).GetMethods();
var sortMethods = methods.Where(m => m.Name == "Sort");
var candidates = sortMethods.Where(m => m.GetParameters().Count() == 3);

var parameterTypes = new Type[] { typeof(byte).MakeArrayType(), typeof(Int32), typeof(Int32) };

foreach(var m in candidates)
{
    // find the best match
}
```

I get 4 methods :

[image: example of 4 candidates]

And I don't know how to programmatically find the best match.

Comment: Basically checking for each parameter if `[MethodParameterType].IsAssignableFrom([TypeToTest])` should be sufficent as a test if the method is invokable with the set of given types.

Comment: thanks @thehennyy but it doesn't work with T[] and byte[].
IsAssignableFrom return false both for array type and elementTypes

Comment: Can you show an example of multiple methods among which you want to find a best one?

Comment: done. But please keep in mind I don't want a solution just for this example, but something general

Comment: You do realize that you are basically trying to reproduce c# compiler's method overload resolution? Thats by all means far from a trivial task, its actually darn complicated once you factor in implicit reference conversions, user defined implicit operators, closeness, genericness, nullables, etc. etc.

Comment: @thehennyy your proposed method is wrong. Simply because all parameters are assignable doesn't mean its the best match.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add, don't forget about generic type variance too...

Comment: @InBetween yes i do. Something partaially working (no unsafe, no ref, no out...) would be ok though

Comment: Well, again, that is one hell of a task. Simply read *7.5.3 Overload Resolution* in c#'s last published specifications to understand what you are up against. Why exactly do you need to do this? Maybe there is an easier solution that doesn't imply trying to mimic, even partially, one of the hardest features in the language.